# PowerShell RegEx Select Line and Parse the Fields

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing, expression

I've a file that contains information about the programs.
What I want is to get some information about a particular prgoram.

This the structure of the file.

```
 sometext...program.EXE;Thu, 04 May 2017 08:58:48 -0700;Wed, 27 Sep 2017 10:50:00 -0700;Wed, 04 Oct 2017 00:00:31 -0700;True;False, 17:38:05.810;30...somtext
```

I was to get the following detail from the above file. each field is separated with `;`

```
    p = program.exe
    dt1 = Thu, 04 May 2017 08:58:48 -0700
    dt2 = Wed, 27 Sep 2017 10:50:00 -0700
    dt3 = Wed, 04 Oct 2017 00:00:31 -0700
    d1 = True
    d2 = False
```

`Get-Content .\file.txt`

So far I have `\W*((?i)program.exe(?-i))\W*` to match it.
But I don't know how to move forward, read all of the fields and parse it.

Comment: try this... `(?i)\W*program\.exe\W*(.*?;)(.*?;)(.*?;)(.*?;)(.*?;)`

Comment: @bulbus this is good...how can I get the values and assign them to variable? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Next try

```
$p,$dt1,$dt2,$dt3,$d1,$d2=@'
sometext...program.EXE;Thu, 04 May 2017 08:58:48 -0700;Wed, 27 Sep 2017 10:50:00 -0700;Wed, 04 Oct 2017 00:00:31 -0700;True;False, 17:38:05.810;30...somtext
'@|
Select-String '(program.exe)[^;]*(?:;([^;]+)){3}(?:;(true|false)){2},' -AllMatches|
ForEach-Object {$_.Matches}|
ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1..3]}|
ForEach-Object {$_.Captures}|
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
$p,$dt1,$dt2,$dt3,$d1,$d2
```

<strike>Can this help you?</strike>

```
@'
sometext...program.EXE;Thu, 04 May 2017 08:58:48 -0700;Wed, 27 Sep 2017 10:50:00 -0700;Wed, 04 Oct 2017 00:00:31 -0700;True;False, 17:38:05.810;30...somtext
'@|
Select-String '([^;]+)' -AllMatches|
ForEach-Object {$_.Matches}|
ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

Comment: this gives me `sometext...program.EXE` as the first object. How can I start with `program.exe only`. Also, I need to store the values to a variable like I've in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
>> sometext...program.EXE;Thu, 04 May 2017 08:58:48 -0700;Wed, 27 Sep 2017 10:50:00 -0700;Wed, 04 Oct 2017 00:00:31 -0700;True;False, 17:38:05.810;30...somtext
>> @'|
>> Select-String '(?i)\W*(program\.exe)\W*(.*?;)(.*?;)(.*?;)(.*?;)(.*?;)'|
>> % {$_.Matches}|
>> % {$p=$_.Groups[1].Value;$dt1=$_.Groups[2].Value;$dt2=$_.Groups[3].Value;$dt3=$_.Groups[4].Value;$d1=$_.Groups[5].Value;$d2=$_.Groups[6].Value}
:\> $p
program.EXE
:\> $dt1
Thu, 04 May 2017 08:58:48 -0700;
:\> $dt2
Wed, 27 Sep 2017 10:50:00 -0700;
:\> $dt3
Wed, 04 Oct 2017 00:00:31 -0700;
:\> $d1
True;
:\> $d2
False, 17:38:05.810;
:\>
```

**OR**

```
IN:  \> "sometext...program.EXE;Thu, 04 May 2017 08:58:48 -0700;Wed, 27 Sep 2017 10:50:00 -0700;Wed, 04 Oct 2017 00:00:31 -0700;True;False, 17:38:05.810;30..
.somtext"|
IN:  >> Select-String '(?i)\W*(program\.exe)\W*(.*?;)(.*?;)(.*?;)(.*?;)(.*?;)' -OutVariable o
OUT:
sometext...program.EXE;Thu, 04 May 2017 08:58:48 -0700;Wed, 27 Sep 2017 10:50:00 -0700;Wed, 04 Oct 2017 00:00:31 -0700;True;False, 17:38:05.810;30...somtext


IN:  \> $f,$p,$dt1,$dt2,$dt3,$d1,$d2=% -inputObject $o.Matches.Groups {$_.Value}
IN:  \> $d2
OUT: False, 17:38:05.810;
```

I assigned each group to the variable required. See if this works. Apologize for any naivety, I'm not well versed with powershell.